# Difference between C# partial classes and Objective C categories?

Tags: c#, objective-c

I am new to Objective C. having spent couple of months in iOS, I am struggling to understand usage of Objective C categories.

Are they same as  C#  partial classes and used to divide huge classes in to methods pertaining to a piece of requirement.

OR there is more to it than just this much ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objective-C categories are a way to add methods to existing classes. They can be compared to .NET extension methods.

The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html) is pretty comprehensive about categories, so I suggest you to read it to fully understand the benefits.

**Note**: One advantage of categories over extension methods, is that you can add both instance and static methods to a class.

Answer (score 4):

They're usually used more like Extension Methods than like Partial Classes.

With a category in Objective-C, you can add methods to a class that anyone in your program can implicitly use as if they're a built in part of the class.

It's definitely *possible* to use them as Partial Classes to split implementations throughout several files, but I'm not sure I've ever seen that used in practice.

Comment: Goin by it's name, I was feeling "category" was more about categorization than extension.